# CodeIgniter MySQL select sum query

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am using model below in CodeIgniter to get the sum of a column:

```
public function b2c_totalsales()
    {
        $this->db->select_sum('total_price');
        $result=$this->db->from('orders_b2c');
        return $result;
    }
```

and in the controller:

```
$data['total_sales']=$this->reports_b2c->b2c_totalsales();
```

and I am getting:

> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_driver could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: views/reports_b2c.php

where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute the query with `get`:

```
$this->db->select_sum('total_price');
$result = $this->db->get('orders_b2c')->row();
return $result;
```

Comment: No problem! Don't forget the `->row()` to get one result or `->result()` to get an array with all of them.

Comment: I see that people are still voting for my answer. Please try to migrate to CodeIgniter 4 if you can, as that new version adds a great deal of features, simplifies the syntax and makes CI4 a Framework that looks a bit more like the leaders of the market.